# Restarted Ubuntu and now none of my USB ports are working

Tags: 20.04, usb

I really am baffled as to what is happening. I simply restarted my PC because it was being a little slow, and now that it has restarted, I am stuck on the login screen without Mouse or Keybaord functionality. I have tried several other keyboards as well as different ports on the machine and nothing changes.

Since it's an RGB keyboard, I can even see it light up during initial boot, but before the Ubuntu login screen shows up the keyboard lights go out and it is unresponsive. I am also now because of this unable to get into the BIOS, or do anything for that matter.

Ubuntu version 20.04 is the version I am using.

Comment: I never changed any settings relating to USB on my PC before rebooting, never changed any BIOS settings or done anything that I know would cause something like this. No power is even delivered over the USB ports once booted

Comment: You can use process of elimination and rule out a hardware issue if you boot a live session (Try Ubuntu from USB installation media). If the problem persists in a live session, then there is probably a hardware issue. I would be concerned that the USB ports don't supply power because Ubuntu has no control over that.

Comment: I was wrong about no power over the ports, I am able to charge my phone for example. But none of my peripherals would work. Now I have removed and reinstalled my GPU, and now the PC won't boot at all. I fear I have bigger issues than random USB ports not working...

Comment: So what was the result of the live session?

Comment: Run `uname -r` to see which kernel you are using.  Some users are [reporting issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956849) with 5.11.0-44 and have had success by reverting to a previous kernel.  You should also run `lsusb -v` to see if you have a *VIA Labs, Inc* device, as that seems to also be part of the issue.  D'OH, just realized you don't have a keyboard ....

Answer (score 1):

I have a computer that does this.

After the computer logs on and the lights go out on the keyboard, I have to unplug the keyboard and mouse and plug them back in.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a laptop machine. If you can open up your desktop, remove the battery, reinsert it, then it would reset the BIOS to your default settings. It should allow you to boot.

Once you boot, you'll want to go into the BIOS, reset your clock, and check whether your USB support can be enabled for the devices you need to use.  For best results, download the user guide for your BIOS to another device or computer that's handy to the Ubuntu desktop you're working on.